# Is it possible to have some sort of incremental autocomplete in Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, autocomplete

I recently got setup with Eclipse for Android development, and I was wondering if there was any sort of incremental autocompletion that could be enabled. Currently, if I were to start typing the letter "a" in an xml layout file, I can see a list of suggestions including everything that uses the `android` namespace. If I wanted to narrow it down to something like `android:layout_marginEnd`, I would have to type out `android:layout_m` just to have the list shorten enough to see the `android:layout_marginEnd` option.

Is there any way I can configure Eclipse to behave like a Unix terminal, so that autocompletion when there is more than one possible suggestion will only complete up to the point of divergence? For example, the letter "a" would autocomplete to `android:`. `android:layo` would autocomplete to `android:layout`. `android:layout_m` would autocomplete to `android:layout_margin`. It would save a heck of a lot of typing!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to type every letter - typing `l` and then `m` will often limit you down to the same subset of options as `android:layout_m`. Unfortunately, there is no option to treat it exactly like a unix terminal.

Comment: Are you sure about that? You can type a partial string (not necessarily the first characters) but not separate ones AFAIK. E.g. "mar" would work for "android:layout_margin", but not "lm".

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure I've done it in Eclipse as well, but I've only tested it recently in IntelliJ and Android Studio. Perhaps Eclipse has changed since then.

Comment: Off topic but... use Studio. You will find it difficult to use Eclipse again.